# How to compare a y variable to all y variable in an array of objects?

Tags: java

Just in case, this would translate to:

```
robots[0].y == y?
robots[1].y == y?
robots[2].y == y?
```

etc...

same thing for x.

I know there must be a way of doing this but my syntax is bad. Here is what I've tried doing:

```
if(robots[].y == y && robots[].x == x){
        //SOMETHING HAPPENS
}
```

Comment: Please explain your problem in greater detail, complete with background information

Comment: I think I know what you are trying to ask. If you want to compare each element's value to a specific value, you can use some kind of loop. The syntax in your `if` statement's boolean expression is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

If robots array contains primitive types (or auto-boxing types) data, you can use the == symbol,
But, if robots contains robots you must use the equals method unless you want to compare the two reference objects then you will need to also use the == symbol.

```
for(int i=0;i<robots.length;i++)
   if (robots[i]== y ) // To compare primitives or objects reference

for(int i=0;i<robots.length;i++)
   if (robots[i].equals (y )) // To compare objects
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8+ [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)(s) you might check that every robot `r` matches ([`allMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-)) like

```
if (Stream.of(robots).allMatch(r -> r.x == x && r.y == y)) {
    //SOMETHING HAPPENS
}
```

Or perhaps you meant to do something **where** the robot matches, in which case [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-). For example, to print, like

```
Stream.of(robots).filter(r -> r.x == x && r.y == y).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop to traverse the array. I am assuming there are y elements in your array. Im not sure what y is so i will use an int in this example. If you comment I can help you if y is a different data type. Comparing more advanced datatypes do not usually use "=="

```
int y = 0; //set y equal to whatever integer you want to check
for(int i = 0; i < robots.size; i++){
    if(robots[i] == y){
        //something happens

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this, the only thing you have to add is the for loop:

```
//robot is your object type    
robot robots[]; // assuming you set values for this guy
robot _compare;

_compare.x = 5;
_compare.y = 10;

for (robot rob: robots)
    if (rob.y == _compare.y && rob.x == _compare.x)
        // Do something
```

Answer (score 0):

You can opt to use reflection, via utility class.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public final class Util {

    public static boolean equalsAll(Object[] array, String fieldName, Object keyField) {

        boolean result = false;
        for (Object item : array) {
            // get class variables
            Field[] fields = item.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field field : fields) {

                // check for field-name
                if (!field.getName().equals(fieldName)) { 
                    continue;
                }

                try {
                    // check for object equality
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    Object object = field.get(item);
                    if (object != null && object.equals(keyField)) {
                        result = true;
                        continue;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

            }

            if (!result) {
                return false; // no matching field name/type.
            }

        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

sample syntax/usage:

```
if(Util.equalsAll(robots, "y", y) && Util.equalsAll(robots, "x", x)) {
   //do something
}
```